# URLDownloadToFile to the same directory

Tags: c++

I am trying to achieve saving a random file from the net to the same directory where the .exe is located. The problem is that I only got it working when specifying the absolute directory.

The last code I tried was:

```
    string home;    
    home = system("echo %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/aaa.gif");

  HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, _T("http://stackoverflow.com/gif.gif"), (TCHAR*)home.c_str(), 0, NULL );
```

Also I tried:

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, _T("http://stackoverflow.com/gif.gif"), "/aaa.gif", 0, NULL );
```

But it isn't working neither.

How can I sort it out? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using _T(".\\aaa.gif") as the file name. This will use the current directory for the file storage location. Alternatively you can also use GetModuleFileName to get the execution path of the exe and work out the path name for your save file.